# fix {" "} issue in react native

Tags: react-native

this is the code...
[image]

and on save it becomes
[image]

any idea how to get rid of {" "}.
it gives Text error (Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.)
[image]

I have tried everything humanly possible. all spaces removed between components but seems something missing...

Comment: Remove all format extensions from vs code and install React native tools  extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. due to ES lint or prettier extension in vs code .
2. before saving , format the code .
3. mostly occurs on pasting the code .